# Parse Cloud File Upload Security

Tags: parse-platform

Since Parse is mainly about cross-platform management of data in the cloud and the security of data is managed through Class-Level and Object-Level (ACL) controls, one is told to pass SDK/REST keys to client-side confidently as long as the data security levels are properly set. For example, file uploads through Parse REST Api requires specific headers like

```
X-Parse-Application-Id
X-Parse-REST-API-Key
```

to https://api.parse.com/1/files/ endpoint. For we have exposed those credentials to the client-side, isn't it possible for anyone to abuse this endpoint to upload countless irrelevant files to the file storage on Parse platform on behalf of the application? Yes, one can secure the data by setting the security levels properly but the file storage? The file storage quota of an application can be exploited, can it not?

The main question is: do that file uploads count as an API request and uploaded files count before they're linked to any object in an application? If they do, isn't it insecure for exploitation?